# how to install libjpeg for pil on windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

I'm converting images formats on windows using python 2.7 and PIL. 
Trying to convert an image to JPG raises this exception:

```
KeyError('JPG',)
```

Traceback:

```
    ...\PIL\Image.py", line 1429, in save
    save_handler = SAVE[string.upper(format)] # unknown format
KeyError: 'JPG'
```

On linux, i solved this by installing the libjpeg, and setting a symbolic link to it's location so PIL could find it.

I'm trying to accomplish the same on Windows. I got the windows format package "jpegsr9.zip" from http://www.ijg.org but couldn't figure how PIL figures these files exist. Trying to place them in the same folder didn't help.

Where should i place the files so this will work on Windows as well? What is the installion process of libjpeg on Windows?

**UPDATE**: JPG exception isn't raised anymore if trying to convert to **"JPEG"** instead of **"JPG"** . This issue doesn't seem to require any additional installations.

Answer (score 1):

JPG exception isn't raised anymore if trying to convert to **"JPEG"** instead of **"JPG"** . This issue doesn't seem to require any additional installations.